# No errors at compile time but does not create one of the class files.

Tags: java, derby

I created a small application Employees Database using Derby. It worked fine add, delete, update and list. But yesterday some thing changed and it would not compile only one class file there rest gets compiled and I see *.class files except one which does not have main. Yesterday I rebooted the computer and today I find  "error: could not find or load main class" error at run time.". Still it does not  create one of the class files. So there are two issues and both seems related to the setting of the environment variables. But, why it would not create only one of the class files?

Comment: C:\Documents\Derby\db>echo %CLASSPATH%
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\db\lib\derby.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip

Comment: Directory of C:\Documents\Derby\db

07/18/2016  08:05 AM               302 DAOFactory.class
07/18/2016  08:05 AM             1,383 Employee.class
07/18/2016  08:05 AM               361 EmployeeConstants.class
07/18/2016  08:05 AM               172 EmployeeDAO.class
07/18/2016  08:15 AM             3,308 EmployeeDBMaintApp.class
07/18/2016  08:05 AM               277 EmployeeReader.class
07/18/2016  08:05 AM               197 EmployeeWriter.class
07/18/2016  08:05 AM             2,008 Validator.class

Comment: 07/17/2016  02:07 AM               142 DAOFactory.java
07/17/2016  01:19 PM             1,472 Employee.java
07/17/2016  11:48 AM               208 EmployeeConstants.java
07/17/2016  11:48 AM                96 EmployeeDAO.java
07/18/2016  08:07 AM             5,227 EmployeeDB.java
07/17/2016  07:37 PM             3,188 EmployeeDBMaintApp.java
07/17/2016  07:16 PM               157 EmployeeReader.java
07/17/2016  11:47 AM               158 EmployeeWriter.java
07/17/2016  07:23 PM             5,348 EmpNotGoodDB.java
07/17/2016  10:46 AM             2,872 Validator.java

Comment: not here! post code in your question. press edit and than paste the code

Comment: EmployeeDB.java does not get compiled. I use javac EmployeeDBMaintApp.java to compile and it also compiles error free. But it does not create EmployeeDB.class file any more. I just tried to change the code so that it could display the employee records from the ArrayList which I am creating in EmployeeDb.java instead of displaying from the Result Set.

Comment: EmployeeDBMaintApp
Welcome to Employee Database System
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: EmployeeDB
        at DAOFactory.getEmployeeDAO(DAOFactory.java:5)
        at EmployeeDBMaintApp.main(EmployeeDBMaintApp.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EmployeeDB
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        .. 2 more

Comment: Can someone please help me to solve the problem why now my EmployeeDB.java class, does not generate EmployeeDB.class file, during compilation of the application? Compiles clean. Runtime error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: EmployeeDB"

Comment: I moved ALL the java files to another directory and compiled. As usual it compiled error free

Comment: **Solved the problem without knowledge:** I copied ALL the java files of the application to another directory and compiled. As usual it compiled error free. Now EmployeeDB.class is created. It runs perfectly!!!!!!!!  I am not sure why just by copying to a different directory now it works, it is creating EmployeeDB.class?????????

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the problem without knowledge:** I copied ALL the java files of the application to another directory and compiled. As usual it compiled error free. Now EmployeeDB.class is created. It runs perfectly!!!!!!!!  I am not sure why just by copying to a different directory now it works, it is creating EmployeeDB.class?????????